# Working with IE9-browser mode in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When i run my application in IE9 and IE10, it works well, But when i run ie9(browser mode) in IE10, a Javascript error occurs related to access permission.

So, is working with ie9(browser mode) in ie10 is not reliable to test an application?

There is no problem when running in ie10, but changing the browser mode causes the error, why?

Comment: Yes, changing browser mode is not a reliable way to test an app "in older IEs". Why an error occurs, it's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: What you mean by older IEs, i'm using IE10 here.

Comment: last time in Win7 I run Emulator for finding bugs for Mobile Safari. After check it I don't found any issue when on real device this is clearly not work :(, Simulator are never helpful

Comment: With "older IEs" I mean IE9. Running IE10 in IE9 browser mode emulates IE9 in IE10, which is not a reliable way to test an app...

Comment: I'm just curious, is there any way that we can enable the js to work well with ie9 browser mode in IE10?

Comment: @Vignesh How would we know without seeing the code!

Comment: @Teemu yeah thats rite, but i was just wanted to know if there is something out there to make it possible without the need of the code actually. i'm sorry about asking that without displaying the code.

Comment: @Vignesh There are probably hundreds of issues like this when emulating IE9 with IE10, every fix (if there's a one) depends on the code triggering an error, a general fix doesn't exist. Plese add the error-causing code into your post.